# Linear Transformation Proof (Show $L_1(v_i)=L_2(v_i)$)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I understand that the properties of scalar multiplication and addition allow for the expansion of $L_1(v)$ and $L_2(v)$ but I dont see how they are equal. They would only be equal if $L_1 = L_2$, but I don't see how.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you expand $L_1(v)$ and $L_2(v)$ you still do not know if they are equal. But
$$L_1(v) = \alpha_1L_1(v_1)+\dots+\alpha_nL_1(v_n) = \alpha_1L_2(v_1)+\dots+ \alpha_nL_2(v_n) = L_2(v)$$
for any $v$. Then $L_1 = L_2$.

Comment: But why is $α_1L_1(v_1)+⋯+α_nL_1(v_n)=α_1L_2(v_1)+⋯+α_nL_2(v_n)$?

Comment: Because by assumption $L_1(v_i) = L_2(v_i)$ for any $i = 1,\dots,n.$

Comment: Oh, I thought we were supposed to prove that assumption. I'm not sure what the point of this question is then?

Comment: Assumption: $L_1 = L_2$ when evaluated on the vectors of a basis. Thesis: $L_1=L_2$ when evaluated on any vector.